# Segmentation fault while visualizing own PointCloud2 Message

Tags: rviz, sensor-msgs, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I wrote a python class which should convert an 2D-Array with intensities to a Pointcloud an publish it.
Unfortunately RViz crashes, as soon as it should show something.
The error is the following:

`Segmentation fault (Memory image written)` (Translation is hand done and may be vague)

Is there any tutorial how to correctly generate a PointCloud2 message in Python?
If not, is somebody able to give me a simple short code block how to do it? I feel like I missed something....

This is the class description:

[sensor_msgs/PointCloud2](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html)

[Python conversion to bits](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/sensor_msgs/html/__PointCloud2_8py_source.html)

This is the python class:
#!/usr/bin/env python

```
import sensor_msgs.msg as smsgs
import std_msgs.msg as stdmsgs
import math as m
import tf

POINTCLOUD_TOPIC = 'sonar'
NODE_NAME = 'adapter'

class Adapter():
    def receive(self):
        self.sonarToPointfield()

    def sonarToPointfield(self):
        
        #  Create Header
        msg_header = stdmsgs.Header()
        msg_header.seq = 1
        msg_header.frame_id = "/map"
        msg_header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()

        #  Create 4 PointFields as channel description
        msg_pf1 = smsgs.PointField()
        msg_pf1.name = 'x'
        msg_pf1.offset = 0
        msg_pf1.datatype = 7
        msg_pf1.count = 1
        
        msg_pf2 = smsgs.PointField()
        msg_pf2.name = 'y'
        msg_pf2.offset = 4
        msg_pf2.datatype = 7
        msg_pf2.count = 1
         
        msg_pf3 = smsgs.PointField()
        msg_pf3.name = 'z'
        msg_pf3.offset = 8
        msg_pf3.datatype = 7
        msg_pf3.count = 1
         
        msg_pf4 = smsgs.PointField()
        msg_pf4.name = 'intensity'
        msg_pf4.offset = 12
        msg_pf4.datatype = 2
        msg_pf4.count = 1
        
        resultList = [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 2]
        resultList = [0, 0, 0, 200]
        
        #  len(resultList) / 4 is the number of points, since every point consists of 4 elements
        #  one point representation (x=FLOAT32, y=FLOAT32, z=FLOAT32, intensity=UINT8) is 13 bytes long
        resultList2 = []
        resultArray = np.zeros((len(resultList) / 4) * 13, dtype=np.ubyte)
        print "len(resultArray): ", len(resultArray)
        for x in range(0, len(resultList)-1, 4):
            tmpArr = np.zeros(13, np.ubyte)
            print "Coords: " + str(resultList[x+0]) + ", " + str(resultList[x+1]) + ", " + str(resultList[x+2]) + ", " + str(resultList[x+3])
            struct.pack_into('fffB', tmpArr, 0, resultList[x+0], resultList[x+1], resultList[x+2], resultList[x+3])
            print "tmpArr: ", tmpArr
            for i in range(len(tmpArr)):
                resultList2.append(tmpArr[i])
                resultArray[((x/4)*13)+i] = tmpArr[i]

        #  Create PointCloud2 instance
        msg_pointcloud2 = smsgs.PointCloud2()
        
        #  Fill message
        msg_pointcloud2.header = msg_header
        msg_pointcloud2.fields = [msg_pf1, msg_pf2, msg_pf3, msg_pf4]
        msg_pointcloud2.data = resultList2
        msg_pointcloud2.width = len(resultList2)
        msg_pointcloud2.height = 1
        msg_pointcloud2.point_step = 13
        msg_pointcloud2.row_step = 1560
        msg_pointcloud2.is_dense = False
        msg_pointcloud2.is_bigendian = True
        
        self.publishPointCloud2(msg_pointcloud2)

    def publishPointCloud2(self, msg_pointcloud2):
        self.pub.publish(msg_pointcloud2)
        self.publishWorldFrame()
        
    def publishWorldFrame(self):
        br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
        br.sendTransform((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), rospy.Time.now(), "/sonar_pointcloud", "/map")
        
    def init(self):
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('sonar_pointcloud', smsgs.PointCloud2)
        rospy.init_node('pcl_adapter')
        self.receive()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    adapter = Adapter()
    adapter.init()
```

Thank you in advance,
Josch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65516/segmentation-fault-while-visualizing-own-pointcloud2-message/) by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The row step was calculated wrong, since I only tested on a simulated input. Using a dynamic row_step worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) with karma: 230 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reported as a bug here: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/649

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-06-20**:
Okay thanks. So there's nothing i can do about it right now?

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-06-21**:
After reviewing this, I think it's probably not a bug in RViz. Couldn't reproduce the crash after fixing the python script posted with the question.